# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0: MongoDB => Express => Angular2 (Angular CLI)

Tags: http, angular, express, typescript, angular-cli

I'm pretty good with Angular2 now but I've never worked with Express or REST. I think I have the server set up correctly now, but I'm having trouble getting my services to transform the data properly.

The reason I'm confident that the server works is because I can navigate to my express route `http://localhost:3000/api/foods` and I can observer my rest api there:

[image]

I've followed the Angular2 [HTTP Client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data-with-http-get) ***Doc to Fetch data with http.get*** but I'm getting the error:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I assume this is because of the `<html>` that can be seen in the image above, but the Docs say that `res.json();` should manage that.

The problem is that I'm an Express/REST noob and I don't know how to transform the data properly. I'm not sure if this an Express issue, a MongoDB issue, or an Angular/Angular CLI configuration issue, and I'm not sure how to find out which it is.

Here is the relevant code:

**food.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Food } from '../../interfaces/diet/food'
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class FoodsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getMongoFoods(): Observable<Food[]>{
    console.log('called getMongoFoods');
    return this.http.get('api/foods')
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
  }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Food = require('./routes/foods');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cutcal');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Please use /api/foods');
});

app.get('/api/foods', function(req, res){
  Food.getFoods(function(err, foods){
    if (err) { throw err; }
    res.json(foods);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('running on port 3000');
```

**foods.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var foodSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  }
});

var Food = module.exports = mongoose.model('Food', foodSchema);

module.exports.getFoods = function(callback, limit){
  Food.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
```

Comment: this is neither `typescript` nor `angular` problem. it's just simply malformed JSON.

Comment: If you can share the network tab where you get the response, the html file you're using and the ts file you're using that'd be good.